# ItemAdded Event - ListView

Tags: android

Is there is any equivalent to ItemAdded event in android listview?
basically I want to check if the new item has some attributes or values then I will do some coloring on it.
I don't want to loop over all items once loading is done, even though I have no idea how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the data that is used in the adapter in your listview.

After updating the data.. there is one method in adapter called `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will refresh the adapter.

Now in adapter's `getView()` method,
implement the logic that can change the color..

Hope it will help you..!!